# Multiple IPA files are generated for a sliced version of app in new Xcode

Tags: xcode

With the latest Xcode, when I'm trying to create IPAs for development profile. With app thinning off, I am getting one universal IPA file as expected. But when I enable app thinning and select a specific device, I am getting multiple IPA files. With older Xcodes (10.1) I still get only one thinned IPA file as expected

Did any one else ran into this issue? Is there any solution for this?

This is the `ExportOptions` plist file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <true/>
    <key>destination</key>
    <string>export</string>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>signingStyle</key>
    <string>automatic</string>
    <key>stripSwiftSymbols</key>
    <true/>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string><teamIDHere></string>
    <key>thinning</key>
    <string>iPhone9,1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With older Xcodes (10.1) I still get only one thinned IPA file as expected

So let’s ask ourselves: what happened in Xcode 10.2? Answer: ABI stability! So the app can be thinned in two different ways, depending whether the target device has Swift built into the system frameworks or not. And you can tell the difference; one thinned app will be larger because it contains the Swift frameworks.

Comment: Thanks.. That makes sense, but in some cases I am seeing more than two IPAs. Is there any reason for that too?

Comment: Well, earlier I asked you to investigate these IPAs and see what difference there is between them. Did you? Is it right that some have the swift frameworks inside them and some don't?

Comment: Yaa. One of the ipa have swift frameworks but the other two doesn't and the package contents and size looks pretty same in those two. I am just wondering what is the difference between those two ipa files.